# Plotting a geom_density plot with a given y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create, with ggplot2, a geom_density plot in which I select which value goes on the y-axis. Given a dataset `n` and its variables `year` and `count`, I wanted to have plot in which the y axis corresponds to the value in the count `column`. For example, in the dataset below:

```
n= structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), count = c(100, 
150, 170, 70, 190)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I wanted a dataset with the values on `count` in the y-axis.

Comment: I think you want the geom_smooth() function, that will make you a GAM or loess smoothed trend line. Geom density is used to plot the kernel density based estimated pdf of your data.

Comment: n %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count)) + geom_smooth()

Comment: The `stat_density()` layer uses the `geom_area` geometry, so if you got precomputed y-values, the `geom_area()` layer would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the geom_smooth() function. Geom_density is used to provide a kernel density-based pdf of *one* of your variables.

Here, you want to show an estimated *relationship* or trend of count against time. Look at the options under ?geom_smooth to achieve your desired effect.

(You would also typically attempt this kind of thing on a larger data set than that provided, but I assume this is to make a reproducible example)